# Date comparison inside a "for loop" in php

Tags: php

I have a set of rows with five fields. My requirement is if "Internal_Deadline" field is greater than "Client_Deadline" in any of the rows, then it has to display a alert saying "Internal Deadline should not be greater than Client Deadline". Now it's checking only with the first row. I need to check with all the rows. Thanks

```
<?php

for( $i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++ )
{
    $task = $_POST['task'.$i];
    $Description = $_POST['Description'.$i];
    $Internal_Deadline = $_POST['Internal_Deadline'.$i];
    $Client_Deadline = $_POST['Client_Deadline'.$i];
    $Actual_Deadline = $_POST['Actual_Deadline'.$i];

    if(strtotime($Internal_Deadline) > strtotime($Client_Deadline)){

        ?>
        <script>alert('Internal Deadline should not be greater than Client Deadline');</script>
        <?php
    }
    else{    

        $result_task=mysql_query("select * from project_plan where p_id='$p_id' and task_no='$i'", $dbconnect1);   
        $row_task=mysql_fetch_array($result_task);
        $id=$row_task['id'];

        if(mysql_num_rows($result_task)!=0){
            $update_result=mysql_query("update project_plan set Task='$task',Description='$Description',Internal_Deadline='$Internal_Deadline',Client_Deadline='$Client_Deadline',Actual_Deadline='$Actual_Deadline' where id='$id'", $dbconnect1);
        }
        else{  
            if($task!=""){
                $que = mysql_query("insert INTO project_plan(task_no,Task,Description,Internal_Deadline,Client_Deadline,Actual_Deadline,Created_Date,p_id) VALUES ('".$i."','".$task."','".$Description."','".$Internal_Deadline."','".$Client_Deadline."','".$Actual_Deadline."','".$current_date."','".$p_id."')", $dbconnect1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indentation is your friend

Comment: test you $_POST variable by printing  it inside the loop

Comment: Yes it's displaying only first row

Comment: add the output of `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Array ( [task2] => test1 [Description2] => [Internal_Deadline2] => 25/02/2014 [Client_Deadline2] => 28/02/2014 [Actual_Deadline2] => [task1] => test [Description1] => [Internal_Deadline1] => 05/02/2014 [Client_Deadline1] => 10/02/2014 [Actual_Deadline1] => [items] => 3 [task3] => test3 [Description3] => [Internal_Deadline3] => 26/02/2014 [Client_Deadline3] => 03/03/2014 [Actual_Deadline3] =>[submit] => Submit )

Comment: I have added three rows and submitted. Above is the print_r function's output.

Comment: Can anyone help me to figure out this issue

Comment: your given post data are never met your     `if(strtotime($Internal_Deadline) < strtotime($Client_Deadline)){` condition.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the length of your for loop is not correct.

You need to run this loop exact same times to the post data count.

secondly i have tried locally with your given data(in your comment). it seems that is not met the condition:

```
  if(strtotime($Internal_Deadline) > strtotime($Client_Deadline)){
```

try like this:
it will skip unnecessary loops. if you have task1,task2,task3 set in post data then it will run for 3 times not 100 times as your implementation.

```
$i=1;
while(isset($_POST['task'.$i]))
{
    $task = $_POST['task'.$i];
    $Description = $_POST['Description'.$i];
    $Internal_Deadline = $_POST['Internal_Deadline'.$i];
    $Client_Deadline = $_POST['Client_Deadline'.$i];
    $Actual_Deadline = $_POST['Actual_Deadline'.$i];

    if(strtotime($Internal_Deadline) > strtotime($Client_Deadline)){

        ?>
        <script>alert('Internal Deadline should not be greater than Client Deadline');</script>
    <?php
    }
    else{

        $result_task=mysql_query("select * from project_plan where p_id='$p_id' and task_no='$i'", $dbconnect1);
        $row_task=mysql_fetch_array($result_task);
        $id=$row_task['id'];

        if(mysql_num_rows($result_task)!=0){
            $update_result=mysql_query("update project_plan set Task='$task',Description='$Description',Internal_Deadline='$Internal_Deadline',Client_Deadline='$Client_Deadline',Actual_Deadline='$Actual_Deadline' where id='$id'", $dbconnect1);
        }
        else{
            if($task!=""){
                $que = mysql_query("insert INTO project_plan(task_no,Task,Description,Internal_Deadline,Client_Deadline,Actual_Deadline,Created_Date,p_id) VALUES ('".$i."','".$task."','".$Description."','".$Internal_Deadline."','".$Client_Deadline."','".$Actual_Deadline."','".$current_date."','".$p_id."')", $dbconnect1);
            }
        }
    }
    $i =$i +1;
}
```

Comment: Hi Awlad, thanks for the reply. I have tried this code but it's not displaying the alert when i'm entered greater date in "Internal_Deadline" than Client_Deadline.

Comment: @user3317777: i have tested it and it works perfectly. can you provided those data that you have tested?

Comment: I have selected "25/02/2014" date in "Internal_Deadline2" field and "22/02/2014" in "Client_Deadline2" and when i click submit it's inserted in database. If "Internal_Deadline" is greater than "Client_Deadline" means it has to show alert.

Comment: Please check the second field Program output: 28/02/2014 is less than  25/02/2014 - Incorrect

Comment: @user3317777: did you check that?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Now the third field Program output is incorrect: 26-02-2014 is greater than 03-03-2014